# How do I create a static class that can be used in any project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, static

I'm trying to create a static class (`IntNode`, `IntList`) that I would be able to access through any project by using the class name.

I've saved the file name as the class name (IntNode.cs), and I added `public` before the class name,  but still it is not recognized on other projects.

What else I'm missing?

Comment: How to add reference to outer file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599722/using-a-class-file-reference-it

Comment: http://iampierremenard.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/dog-dude-wait-what.jpg

Comment: @ByteBlast: Or just someone at the very beginning of his journey.

Comment: This question is incomplete. Please tell us what is the context, are you in the same solution?

Comment: yes, i am in the beginning of my journey, and no, i am NOT a troll.
@ByteBlast - you must have a very exciting life behind your keyboard.

i'm studying out of a very doughtful book in a language that is definitely not english, so i'm trying my best to be clear.

i understood that it is possible to create a class that doesn't have a Main method. just includes a lot of methods that are commonly used (for example - dealing with arrays - reading, writing, calculations Etc.)

once existing, is it possible to use from a different solution without copying the file into the current solution?

Comment: @user2315710 misunderstanding, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The projects that want to use that class need to do one of the following two things:

1. Reference the assembly the classes have been defined in.
2. Directly add the *.cs files to the project. You can add them as a local copy or as a link.

Option 1 is preferred.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Thanks, I added that. In this scenario, it would be unusual, but there are other scenarios where it is very common, e.g. app development via Xamarin. The code can be the same for different platforms, but you need one project file per platform.

Comment: (Deleted my original comment suggesting adding option 2 once you'd done that). It's also common when dealing with [tag:XNA] (one project for each target platform) which is where I've used it in the past.