# C# - Detect if application has been launched by another program

Tags: c#, startup, detect

I've made a Launcher for my game, and the launcher auto-download and patches the game.
But, how can I check if the game has been launched by the Launcher? Is there a way to do it without using Command Line Arguments?

Comment: you can make launcher to add some kind of log, and then check log file when game starts

Comment: Interesting question. Surely it is possible, but I think this could be platform specific.

Comment: Well, if you dont just call "mygame.exe" you can using .net use the exe, and have the main routine do "stuff off dont call me direct" and yet use the classes etc from with in it... maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your launcher is .net application, you can start your application not from command line, but by calling `Main()` function (from exported class).

If your launcher is not .net application and your application works on Windows only, then you can try to find launcher's window (using `FindWindow` function) from main application, send message using `SendMessage` WinApi function, and check result.

These articles might be usefull:

1. [Importing .net classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599722/using-a-class-file-reference-it)
2. [Finding windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. [Sending messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)
4. [Importing dll functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450783/how-to-use-dllimport-in-c)

Comment: ok, but if someone's else decompile my launcher, he can just make its own and the game will start without problems? and how I can start the  game by calling the Main() method? (my game is made in Unity)

Comment: @Unity-ThiagoSouza to prevent someone make new launchers you should use obfuscation. To run you `Main()` method from your launcher you should add add reference to your `Game.exe` or `Game.dll` made by unity. After that you can create object of your class (like `MyGameNamespace.MyGameClass`) (if it is not static) and run `Main()` method.